# How to highlight selected slice in fuisonchart pie?

Tags: fusioncharts

1) I have a piechart which is implemented using fusionchart, my problem is when I click on slice it should be highlighted.

how to do this using fusionchart pie?

2) When a pie chart doesnot have a value it shows no data to display message, but I need to display the caption, itseems it doesnot appear when no data is found.

how to show caption when no data is there to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In FusionCharts pie's active state is normally denoted by slice in / out state. And there is no such attribute defined to set color of a sliced out pie element. However they have attribute to set hover effect (`showHoverEffect`).

However, You can play with their exposed API, can achieve this. Please refer to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pallab/fmd9xfwj/).

What I have done here is, tapped on the `DataPlotClickEvent` and overwrite the palette colors which ultimately affect the pie color. But this has its own downside, as the chart is re-rendered each time the slice-in out feature is no more active. The chart renders with a new palette in its default state.

```
'dataplotclick': function(evtObj, argObj) {
    var chart = evtObj && evtObj.sender,
        hitIndex = argObj.index,
        rplceColr = highPaletteClrs[hitIndex],
        clrArr = paletteClrs.slice(0),
        clrStr;

    clrArr.splice(hitIndex, 1, rplceColr);
    clrStr = clrArr.join(',');

    if(chart) {
        chart.setChartAttribute('paletteColors', clrStr);
    }

}
```

And for your second requirement of showing the chart only with caption, we can render a chart with all data / set value as '0'.Like:

```
"data": [{
    "label": "Teenage",
    "value": "0"
}, {
    "label": "Adult",
    "value": "0"
}, {
    "label": "Mid-age",
    "value": "0"
}, {
    "label": "Senior",
    "value": "0"
}]
```

Hope this will give a starting point for you. :)

Comment: Thank you pallab, but  I need to highlight the border of the slice when it is sliceout?

Comment: Well, You can entirely manipulate the data and create customization. You already have the index, so now you know which data element you need to customize. Customize the JSON data and reassign it with `setChartData` or `setJSONData` method.

Comment: I new to fusionchart so can i get any examples regarding my problem

Comment: , I got the index using dataplotclick event, i can find out which index slice is sliced out, while slice out how can i setJSONData method and highlight the border of a particular slice

Comment: If you refer to the fiddle I have shared in my answer, you can find how I have used the `setChartAttribute` method. `setJSONData` is a similar method. Only difference is now you need to change the whole data and not an attribute. This are API method not related to your slice in / out state. However if you want to retain the 'state' you may have to set `isSliced` property on the correct data element.

Comment: setJSONData method It renders my whole chart again, but i don't want to re-render my chart, i need to update my value and make the slice highlight.How can i do using setChartAttribute method?.var chart = evtObj && evtObj.sender;if(chart){chart.setChartAttribute("showPlotBorder" : "1";). when i use this onclicking on slice my all slice get boreder

Comment: Through, `setChartAttrobute` you can only update chart level ( applicable to the whole chart or all chart elements) attributes. You can't update a single element, through this. The only easy option is to update the whole data and re-render the chart.